# Inkscape: Require min inner angle for path, for router

Tags: vector, inkscape

I have path I want to cut out with a CNC router.

The router, however, has a min drill size that can't reach tiny crevices.

Is there a way I can constrain a path to a minimum angle? For example, "Outset" but only on those parts of the path that are too narrow and not the entire path.

Simplified example of some narrow inner angles:
[image: inner angle]

Answer (score 1):

You could select the corner node using the *Edit Paths by Nodes Tool (F2)*, and turn it into a symmetrical smooth node by clicking on the *Make Selected Nodes Symmetric* button, and then adjust the Bézier handles to make a gap just big enough for the drill bit.

For example:

[image]

Comment: In the next Inkscape version, there will be an option to do something similar automatically, using the 'fillet/chamfer' live path effect, where one can define a radius for the corners. Currently, this needs to be done manually.

Comment: @Moini - that sounds like a nice feature. I look forward to trying it out.

Comment: It is :) Screenshots, video and an incomplete description here: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/1.0#Fillet.2FChamfer_LPE

Comment: Oh, and you can try it out any time: https://inkscape.org/release/master/?latest=1